# asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC Issue to edit/insert issue

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Issue with my code, more likely an understanding issue.
I have a Model that contains the data for a Soccer match-up.
This score match-up has two teams home/guest

Match Model:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Match
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Anpfiff ist ein Pflichtfeld!")]
        public DateTime Anpfiff { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Heim ist ein Pflichtfeld!")]
        public Team Heim { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gast ist ein Pflichtfeld!")]
        public Team Gast { get; set; }

        public string Ergebnis90 { get; set; }
        public string Ergebnis { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Team Model:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Team
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Teamname ist ein Pflichtfeld!")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "ISO ist ein Pflichtfeld!")]
        public string Iso { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gruppe ist ein Pflichtfeld!")]
        public string Gruppe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Database has therefor a Match Table contains only the id from the Teams.
But if i try to pass only an ID within the model on my View it is not working because it is expecting an entire team object.

And basically i have no id how to create this, and what i have to do in my controller & View to handle also teams.

I hope i was able to explain my point.

Thanks for your help
Lars

Comment: How did you generated the model? Is CodeFirst? Or was generated from database? Or other?

Comment: Code First, and than migrate and update

Answer (score 0):

Add the id reference keys.

Check this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints):

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId)
            .HasConstraintName("ForeignKey_Post_Blog");
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can do operations using the ids.